# When using $(document).on("click",".class",function(){ } how do i reference the button that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).on("click",".gbut",function(){      
    console.log(this.getAttribute("data-X"));
```

Each button has a `data-x` attribute and I need to be able to get the button that was clicked. Using `function(this)` doesn't work, and using `console.log($(this).getAttribute("data-X"));` doesn't work.  I've searched a lot but there is no solution for using `on("click","class",function()`...

Comment: It's `$(this).data("x")` or `$(this).data("X")` depending on the capitalization.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9t4pdceq/

Comment: Welcome UrboyJojo. Within your click handler function `this` will refer to the particular `".bgut"` element that was clicked, noting that `this` is the DOM element not a jQuery object. So `this.getAttribute("data-X")` should return that attribute if it exists, or `$(this).attr("data-X")`, but *not* `$(this).getAttribute("data-X")` because `.getAttribute()` is the DOM method and `.attr()` is the jQuery method.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for the tips this will be useful later!

Comment: @nnnn `this.dataset.x` would be the adequate DOM way to access the data attribute.

Comment: @Pointy https://jsfiddle.net/9t4pdceq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's built-in `data` method:

```
console.log($(this).data("x"));
```

See the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/)